Error with MockMVC and Spring boot integration test
I am trying to create an integration Test for my Spring boot App. For this, I followed the following tutorial: https://programandoenjava.com/pruebas-de-integracion-en-spring-boot/
This is my code:
@SpringBootTest(classes = ArticulosControllerImpl.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ArticulosControllerIT {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private final String ARTICULOS_BASE_URL = "/articulos";

    @Test
    public void CUANDO_se_llama_a_articulos_ENTONCES_el_estado_es_200() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(ARTICULOS_BASE_URL))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers
                        .content()
                        .contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}

But when executing my test I get the following error. I guess it's because in my controller I am using an ArticulosService bean but I don't know how to fix it and in that same service I'm using other beans. Any solutions please?
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.ulises.mybartpv.articulos.rest.controllers.impl.ArticulosControllerImpl required a bean of type 'com.ulises.mybartpv.articulos.services.ArticulosService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ulises.mybartpv.articulos.services.ArticulosService' in your configuration.

Thanks

I decided to change the approach by using TestRestTemplate as follows:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ArticulosControllerIT {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private ArticulosService articulosService;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    @Autowired
    private ArticuloRepository articuloRepository;
    private final String ARTICULOS_BASE_URL = "/articulos";
    private String host;
    private HttpHeaders headers;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        host = "http://localhost:" + port;
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
    }

    @Test
    void CUANDO_se_llama_a_articulos_ENTONCES_el_estado_es_200() throws Exception {
        HttpEntity<Void> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
        ResponseEntity<GetArticulosResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(host + ARTICULOS_BASE_URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
        List<ArticuloDTO> articulos = Objects.requireNonNull(response.getBody()).getArticulos();
    }
}


If you don’t need to test your bean logics in this specific test, you should probably mock your bean with the @MockBean annotation.
You can follow this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web

It's an integration test, I need to test the whole flow

You can achieve this by merely including the autowired Service in the test class and including the implementation of that service in @SpringBootTest annotation.
Also, do remember to annotate the implementation of ArticulosService with @Service annotation.
E.g.:
@SpringBootTest(classes = ArticulosControllerImpl.class, ArticulosServiceImpl.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ArticulosControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ArticulosService articulosService;

    private final String ARTICULOS_BASE_URL = "/articulos";

    @Test
    public void CUANDO_se_llama_a_articulos_ENTONCES_el_estado_es_200() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(ARTICULOS_BASE_URL))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers
                    .content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}

and
@Service
public ArticulosServiceImpl implements ArticulosService {}

PS: Please be aware of either using mock implementation or test configuration if some write logic is handled by the method of this service as it might lead to bad data otherwise.
Hope it helps!!

I keep getting the same error. I decided to switch to using TestRestTemplate

You have to either include ArticulosServiceImpl.class in the @SpringBootTest annotation or remove the controller class as well and open the scope to scan all the classes and find the implementation. Have updated my answer. Thanks for being patience.
